# "Variable ... must occur on both sides of this | pattern"

Tags: syntax, ocaml

As I was typing up some code in OCaml, I wanted to match two cases at once (since the function I'm writing is commutative):

```
type something = 
  | Two of int * int
  | One of int

let my_function p q =
  match p, q with
    | Two (_, _) as two, One (x)
    | One (x), Two (_, _) as two -> (* some value *)
    | _ -> (* some other value *)
;;
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Variable two must occur on both sides of this | pattern
```

The problem doesn't occur when I remove the `as` statement, but I need it for the logic purposes. Why can't I do it like this? Will I have to resort to rewriting the logic twice?

Comment: I found a solution. The second `|` in the match statement was maching `One (x), Two(_, _)` as a single value of type `something * something`. Adding parentheses fixes the problem: `One (x), (Two (_, _) as two)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`as` has lower precedence than `,`. Hence you should put parenthesis around `Two (_,_) as two`.